# Loss of Conv-neural-network not decreasing, instead obsoleting

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have a convolutional neural network in vgg architecture "style" (down below) to classify images if there is a cat on the picture, or a dog. My training set contains 25000 images cropped to 256px each side. I tried different learning rates, different loss functions and much more but my loss keeps fluctuating between 0.692 and 0.694, but it will not decrease...

```
normalize = transforms.Normalize(
    mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
    std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
)

transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(256),
    transforms.CenterCrop(256),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    normalize
])

# Output = [isDog, isCat]
train_data_list = []
train_data = []
target_list = []
plotlist = []
train_files = listdir("data/catsdogs/train/")


def loadTrainData():
    global train_data_list
    global train_data
    global target_list
    print("Loading data now...")

    amount = len(listdir("data/catsdogs/train/"))
    current = 0

    for i in range(amount):
        r = random.randint(0, len(train_files) - 1)
        file = train_files[r]
        train_files.remove(file)

        img = Image.open("data/catsdogs/train/" + file)
        img_tensor = transform(img)  # (3, 256, 256)

        isCat = 1 if 'cat' in file else 0
        isDog = 1 if 'dog' in file else 0
        target = [isCat, isDog]

        train_data_list.append(img_tensor)
        target_list.append(target)

        if len(train_data_list) >= 64:
            train_data.append((torch.stack(train_data_list), target_list))
            train_data_list = []
            target_list = []

        current = current + 1
        print("Loaded: {:.1f}%".format(current * 100 / amount))
    print("Loaded data successfully!")


class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Network, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)

        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)

        self.conv5 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv6 = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)

        self.dropout = nn.Dropout2d()
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=3, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(5184, 1296)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1296, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Block 1
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)

        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.relu(x)

        x = self.pool(x)

        # Block 2
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.relu(x)

        x = self.conv4(x)
        x = self.relu(x)

        x = self.pool(x)

        # Block 3
        x = self.conv5(x)
        x = self.relu(x)

        x = self.conv6(x)
        x = self.relu(x)

        x = self.pool(x)

        x = x.view(-1, 5184)

        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)

        return torch.sigmoid(x)


model = Network()
model = model.cuda()

optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001, weight_decay=0.0016)


def train(epoch):
    global optimizer

    model.train()
    batch_id = 0
    for data, target in train_data:
        data = data.cuda()
        target = torch.Tensor(target).cuda()

        data = Variable(data)
        target = Variable(target)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        out = model(data)
        criterion = F.binary_cross_entropy

        loss = criterion(out, target)
        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()

        plotlist.append(loss)

        print('Train Epoch: {},  {:.0f}% ,\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
            epoch, 100. * batch_id / len(train_data), loss.item()
        ))
        batch_id = batch_id + 1


loadTrainData()

for epoch in range(25):
    train(epoch)

plt.plot(plotlist)
plt.show()
plt.ylabel("Loss")
plt.savefig("lossPlot.png")
```

Here is a plot of my loss over 5 iterations:
[image]

Also with a higher learning rate the fluctuation only gets stronger, for 0.1 lr between 0.5 and 0.7.

Comment: try with less lr like  e-3

Comment: Remove `weight_decay` from optimizer, if this doesn't help go with `1e-4` and overfit on single batch of data instead of `25k` example. BTW. `Variable` is deprecated, don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried adding momentum to your SGD optimizer?

```
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1, weight_decay=0.0016, momentum=0.9)
```

Or, a different optimizer such as Adam or AdaDelta, which will use adaptive learning rate?

Also, it does not look like your training data is shuffled - can it happen than some batches have all cats and some batches have all dogs, pulling the gradient descent in different in opposite directions every few steps? It may be better to shuffle your training data after every epoch and do the batching on top of that. `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` class may be of some help in this.

What's the naming scheme of your files? Do the variables 'isCat' and 'isDog' have correct values?

What happens when you try to train on only 100 examples - is your model able to learn the train data in this simple case - this should hopefully rule out some obvious bugs.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Variable was the right call here.

When I remove it and put Adam in, it works quite ok I guess.
The loss curve looks much better, as well I think I can see when the training is overfitting the network.
But still the loss is heavily obsoleting...
[image]